# Split ArrayList in multiple ArrayLists where values are same

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

Well im stuck on this point.

im trying to make sort function what does this.

```
parentarraylist = [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,1];
*magic*
childarraylist1 = [1,1,1,1];
childarraylist2 = [2,2,2,2];
childarraylist3 = [3,3,3];
```

the magic part is where im stuck.

i have tryied putting it in an for loop(the parent) and checking on the value. like this

```
int i = 0;
int finder = 0;
ArrayList<int> initArray = new ArrayList();
for(int list : parentarraylist){
    if(i == 0){
        finder = list
    }
    if(finder == list){
           initArray.add(list);
           parentarraylist.remove(list);
    }else{
        new ArrayList *value of list* =  new ArrayList(); 
        finder = list;
        *value of list*.add(list);
    }
}
```

this results in a view errors like
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
and i cant set *value of list*

what can i do to make this work?

Comment: Doing different coding but getting same error but its throwing inconsistent.

Comment: im getting the error always.... im my code im trying to sort on dates

Comment: can you explain again what's the input and what's the desired output?

Comment: the input is = `parentarraylist = [1,1,1,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,1];`
the desired output is: `childarraylist1 = [1,1,1,1];
childarraylist2 = [2,2,2,2];
childarraylist3 = [3,3,3];`

Comment: @Blackbelt my code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208804/android-exception-concurentmodificationexception

Comment: i can afford a hashmap if list.remove is possible (the arrays are max 5000 objects large)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little snippet should help you achieve your goal:

```
//maps will hold ALL unique integer as it's key
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> maps = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

//your initial array, written inline for clarity
ArrayList<Integer> parentarraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList( new Integer[] {1,1,1,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,1}));

//get the iterator so that we won't need another temporary int variable for loop
Iterator<Integer> iterator = parentarraylist.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    //next = current integer in our array
    Integer next = iterator.next();

    //check if we have already have current integer or not
    if(!maps.containsKey(next)){
        //we don't have it, initialise an arraylist for this specific integer
        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        x.add(next);

        //put it to our map holder
        maps.put(next, x);
    } else {
        //already have it, add directly
        maps.get(next).add(next);
    }
}
```

This codes will print something like this:

```
printMap(maps);
//1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
//2 = [2, 2, 2, 2]
//3 = [3, 3, 3]
```

> printMap() is taken from this answer: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
   Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
       it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> parent = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        parent.add(3);
        parent.add(1);
        parent.add(1);
        parent.add(2);
        parent.add(3);
        parent.add(3);
        parent.add(1);

        for(int i : parent)
        {
            boolean check = false;
            for(ArrayList<Integer> result : results)
            {
                if(result.size() > 0)
                {
                    if(result.get(0) == i)
                    {
                        check = true;
                        result.add(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!check)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.add(i);
                results.add(temp);
            }
        }

        for(ArrayList<Integer> i : results)
        {
            for(int j : i)
            {
                System.out.print("" + j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
333
111 
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you remove an element from an array over which you are iterating. The

```
parentArrayList.remove(list);
```

causes the error here. If you remove this line your program will work. At the moment I do not see the benefit of removing the item from the parentArrayList for your sorting algorithm so just delete it and you are good to go.

Comment: i dont know if i can afford it(the extra loops)